# Calling static methods in a static class via XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Searched around and could not find a response for this. Does anybody know of a way to call a static method from a static class within XAML. I know that it is possible to call a static method from a regular class using ObjectDataProvider by doing something like:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="mthd" ObjectType="{x:Type l:MyClass}" MethodName="MyStaticMethod">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <sys:String>Test</sys:String>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

I have tried this with the static class and it fails. Since the static class cannot be instantiated with the exception of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Can something similar to this be done for static classes in .Net 4.0? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the above for static classes?

Comment: I definitely have. Since the static class cannot be instantiated i get the following exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Why would it need an instance of a class to call a static method on the class and not the instance? Makes no sense to me...

Comment: I believe that ObjectDataProviders either instantiate an object of the specified type (using ObjectType) or use an existing object (using ObjectInstance) and then call methods from there.

Comment: ObjectDataProvider, as its name implies, needs some object to act on, either specified by `ObjectType` or `ObjectInstance`. If you specify an object, it can well invoke a static method of the objects's class, but unfortunately it does not work without an instance.

Comment: @Bambu: From looking at some source code it seems like the `ObjectDataProvider` will create an instance from the type if none is provided directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating something like an `ObjectDataProvide` is really simple, you just need to use a bit of reflection. Get the class type via a `Type` property right from XAML along with the method name and parameters, then use [`GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05eey4y9.aspx) with the right `BindingFlags` and invoke it with the passed parameters.

Comment: Right, you might derived a `ClassDataProvider` from [DataSourceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.datasourceprovider.aspx) and define properties similar to `ObjectDataProvider`. You would have to override `BeginQuery` and apply new data by `OnQueryFinished`.

Comment: @MaxMazur: You have to use "@"-notation, otherwise people other than the post's owner will not be notified of your comment.

Comment: Could you provide an example for this @Clemens ?